# Using dynamic data in a progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, progress-bar

I am trying to figure out how I can use my own data in the progress bar from progressBar.js. I am not sure how to set my data into the code to get the progress bar to run in a dynamic format.

I am wanting to set `total_goals` as the 100% figure. Then I want the progress bar to scale to what the goals completed would be in terms of `total_goals`, ie: `goals_completed` / `total_goals`. Then use my `goal_percent` as the text value within the circle.

My values are being sent from PHP in a json encoded form.

```
var total_goals = result.total_goals;
var goals_completed = result.goals_completed;
var goal_percent = result.completion_percentage;
$('#total-goals').html(total_goals);
$('#goals-completed').html(goals_completed);
$('#goal-percentage').html(goal_percent);
```

For example sake:

Total goals = 6

Goals completed = 3

Goal Percentage = 50%

```
 step: function(state, circle) {
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

    var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
    if (value === 0) {
      circle.setText('');
    } else {
      circle.setText(value);
    }

  }
});
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

bar.animate(1.0);
```

UPDATE

```
var total_goals;
var goals_completed;
var goal_percent;

    function goalBar(){
        $.ajax({ 
                url: "ajax-php/goal-bar.php",
                type: "get",
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                  //console.log(result);
                    if (result == "Error!") {
                        alert("Unable to retrieve goal bar info!");
                        alert(result);
                    } else {
                        total_goals = result.total_goals;
                        goals_completed = result.goals_completed;
                        goal_percent = result.completion_percentage;
                        $('#total-goals').html(total_goals);
                        $('#goals-completed').html(goals_completed);
                        $('#goal-percentage').html(goal_percent);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
                    console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
                }
            });
            //Goal Bar 

var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle('#goal-bar-container', {
  color: '#aaa',
  // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
  // prevent clipping
  strokeWidth: 4,
  trailWidth: 1,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  text: {
    autoStyleContainer: false
  },
  from: { color: '#aaa', width: 1 },
  to: { color: '#333', width: 4 },
  // Set default step function for all animate calls
  step: function(state, circle) {
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

    var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
    if (value === 0) {
      circle.setText('0');
    } else {
      circle.setText(value);
    }

  }
});
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

bar.animate(goals_completed/total_goals);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0    
    }
    goalBar();
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/72tkyn40/

Comment: Can you please provide you source code ? i have the same issue and i'm having errors first with ProgressBar such as "TypeError: element is null "from progressbar.js file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `bar.animate(1.0);` to `bar.animate(goals_completed/total_goals);`

The value in that line determines what percentage of the circle is filled. So, you need to pass in your variables divide to change out the `1.0` (which equals 100%).

https://jsfiddle.net/72tkyn40/4018/

Comment: Thanks. Do you see why this wouldn't be working in my function? I included my progress bar code within the function to be able to use the dynamic variables, but they keep coming up undefined.

Comment: Try defining your variables as global first (outside of any function: `var goals_completed;` etc) and in your `ajax` update the variables by leaving out the `var` part for each.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that and now the progressBar.js file is throwing a bunch of errors for the values being null. I updated the code in my question.,

Comment: after the line `//Goal Bar` add in `console.log(goals_completed)`. What do you get for this value?

Comment: It comes up undefined. The values within my ajax work as I am assigning them to id's on the page. See pic.

Comment: Keep in that `console.log(goals_completed)` and change this `function goalBar(){` to `function goalBar(goals_completed){`

Comment: Ah...I think I see the problem. You're calling the function `goalBar` AFTER you set up the progress bar. You need to call this first in order to have the variables ready for the progress bar function. You don't really even need the `goalBar` function. You can simple wrap all of that part of the script in a document ready.

Comment: I don't get it. Even removing the function it is still showing as undefined.

Comment: Yes, I did. I just figured it out. I put the code within the ajax brackets and it works. Are ajax variables global outside of the brackets?

Comment: Yes...sorry...I should have mentioned that...to be able to use the variables populated from the ajax, you need to put the code for the progress bar in your ajax `success` call.

Comment: This is what really needed